# Fix last frame of three.js looping animation

Tags: animation, three.js

I used three.js blender plugin to export the pose animations.
The original animations don't have a loop property, therefore the last frame of the animations doesn't equal to the first frame.

So, instead of going back and fixing all the blend files, I want to find a javascript solution.

1. Copy the first frame and append it to the last frame of said animation, and fix the duration.

OR

2. If possible, prevent three.js from blending frames and fix the duration (my animations have keys in every frame so the animations may look decent without "smoothing", unless they are played in slow motion)

Answer (score -1):

Well, I just figured out I can edit the json before it was parsed by three.js

```
function fixjson(json){
    var a = json.animations;
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        var h = a[i].hierarchy;
        var f = 1/a[i].fps;
        a[i].length += f;
        for(var j=0; j<h.length; j++){
            var keys = h[j].keys;
            var n = {};
            for(var x in keys[0]){
                n[x] = keys[0][x];
            }
            n.time = a[i].length-0.001; //don't know why, AnimationMixer skip the last frame if the time equals to the animation duration
            keys.push(n);
        }
    }
}
```